# Qt background-color и QTextEdit

Tags: qt

С помощью QT пишу приложение, все объекты расположены в группу. У групп есть background-color. При нанесении цвета фона на группу, цвет видно сквозь QTextEdit. Как исправить данное положение?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, это действительно так. Как видно на снимке, у *QTextEdit* есть только 2 функции, меняющие цвет элемента.

[image]

Самым лучшим выходом в данном случае будет создание другого элемента под ним с соблюдением такой же ширины и длины. К примеру, *QGraphicsView* с тем же цветом.